# Append a variable to each column in a dataframe object

Tags: python, dataframe

Trying to solve a trading problem, but rephrasing it in a different way.

I have an array of countries as

```
countries = {'country_name':  ['France','Germany','Italy','Japan']}
```

For each country, I have a CSV stored on my laptop. Each CSV has 3 columns [Date, Birth, Death].
I am making for loop on Array and reading the CSV and creating a dataframe object.

```
countries = {'country_name':  ['France','Germany','Italy','Japan']}
countries = pd.DataFrame(countries)
for country in countries['country_name']:
  country_file_name = country + '.csv'
  vars()[country] = pd.read_csv(country_file_name)
  ## Here I want to append country to each column except index
```

When I do `France.head()`

I get the output as **France**

```
index        Birth    Deaths
2020-01-01   9        10
2002-01-02   5        12 
...
2002-12-10   14       10
```

But I want the output as **France**

```
index        France_Birth    France_Deaths
2020-01-01     9             10
2002-01-02     5             12 
....
2002-12-10     14            10
```

Note - I do not want to do `France.columns= ['France_Birth','France_Deaths']` because it will take me days to do it for all the csv.

I am using jupyternote book here.
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1aOg3eOhsigbewAhRwQE1QsxGDKzEPyW5?usp=sharing

Note sure there is any way to this or I have to change my approach.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be achieved using the rename function of pandas.Dataframe:

```
countries = {'country_name':  ['France','Germany','Italy','Japan']}
countries = pd.DataFrame(countries)
for country in countries['country_name']:
  country_file_name = country + '.csv'
  vars()[country] = pd.read_csv(country_file_name).rename(columns=lambda s: country + "_" + s)
```

You can check the documentation [here](https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-pandas-dataframe-rename/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20use%20the%20rename,any%20row%20%2F%20column%20name%20individually.&text=Specify%20the%20original%20name%20and,is%20for%20the%20columns%20name.).